# Embedded SQL in C program using db2

Tags: sql, c, db2

I have a program in c that prompts the user to enter a product manufacturer and  should make a query based on the users input to print all of the products that that manufacturer makes, whether they are PCs, Laptops, or Printers.  Something is wrong here however, as I get two sql states after it returns one row:

SQLSTATE-02000 and SQLSTATE=24000

Neither of these are in the sql error codes that I've searched.

Below I've included my .c file and the .sql schema I'm working with.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  /*** header file for ORACLE definitions ***/
  exec sql include sqlca;

  int print_sql_state(char *code){
    printf("\nSQLSTATE=%s\n", code);
  }

  int main()
  {
    /*** Variable Declaration Block ***/
    exec sql begin declare section;
      char login[129], password[129];
      char SQLSTATE[6];

      /*query based on*/
      char maker[40];
      /*results based on product*/
          int model;
          char type[40];
      /*results based on type of product*/
          float speed;
          int ram;
      int hd;
      float screen;
      int price;
    exec sql end declare section;

    /*** handler for error ***/
    exec sql whenever sqlerror goto report_error; 
    exec sql whenever not found goto notfound;



    /*** Prompt user for login name and password ***/
    printf("Username=");
    gets(login);
    printf("Password=");
    char *pass_string = malloc(128);
    pass_string=getpass("");
    strcpy(password, pass_string);

    /*** Connect to DB ***/
    exec sql connect :login
       identified by :password;

    printf("\nCONNECTION SUCCESSFUL\n");

      /*** INSERT RECORD WITH VALUES PROVIDED BY USER ***/
    while(1){ 
      printf("\nInput manufacturer:");
      scanf("%s", &maker);
      if (maker==-1) /* end loop */
        return 0;

            /*** cursor declaration ***/
      exec sql declare specs_1 cursor for
          SELECT P.model, P.speed, P.ram, P.hd, P.price
          FROM Product PR, PC P
          WHERE PR.model = P.model AND PR.maker = :maker
          UNION
          SELECT L.model, L.speed, L.ram, L.hd, L.price
          FROM Product PR, Laptop L
          WHERE PR.model = L.model AND PR.maker = :maker;

          /*seperate query since not Union Compatible*/
      exec sql declare specs_2 cursor for
          SELECT P.model, P.price
          FROM Product PR, Printer P
          WHERE PR.model = P.model AND PR.maker = :maker;

        exec sql open specs_1;
        /*** TRAVERSE RESULT SET WITH CURSOR ***/
        while(1){ 
          EXEC SQL
          FETCH specs_1 into :model, :speed, :ram, :hd, :price;
          printf("\nModel = %d, Speed = %f, Ram = %d, hd = %d, Price = %d",
                           model, speed, ram, hd, price);
        }

        exec sql open specs_2;
        /*** TRAVERSE RESULT SET WITH CURSOR ***/
        while(1){ 
          EXEC SQL
          FETCH specs_2 into :model, :price;
          printf("\nModel = %d, Price = %d", model, price);
        }

          continue;
      exec sql close specs_1;
      exec sql close specs_2;

      notfound:
          printf("\nNO DATA");
          print_sql_state(SQLSTATE);
          exec sql close specs_1;
          exec sql close specs_2;
    }


    report_error:
        printf("\nCONNECTION ERROR\n");
        print_sql_state(SQLSTATE);
        return 1;           
  }
```

And the SQL

```
  CREATE TABLE Product(
      maker VARCHAR(50),
      model INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      type VARCHAR(10) /*PC, Laptop, or Printer*/
      );

  CREATE TABLE PC(
      model INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, /*model number*/
      speed REAL,
      ram INTEGER,
      hd INTEGER,
      price INTEGER /*"in dollars"*/
      ;

  CREATE TABLE Laptop(
      model INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      speed REAL,
      ram INTEGER,
      hd INTEGER,
      price INTEGER,
      screen INTEGER
      );

  CREATE TABLE Printer(
      model INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, /*model number*/
      price INTEGER /*"in dollars"*/
      );
```

EDIT::: The output of my program when typing 'Dell' as the "maker"

```
  Username=me
  Password=

  CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL

  Input manufacturer:Dell

  Model = 1, Speed = 3.400000, Ram = 4000, hd = 125, Price = 999
  NO DATA
  SQLSTATE=02000

  CONNECTION ERROR

  SQLSTATE=24000
```

EDIT::  These are the test inserts I've been using.

```
  INSERT INTO Product Values('Alien', 5, 'PC');
  INSERT INTO PC Values(5, 3.0, 8000, 500, 1299);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('HP', 7, 'PC');
  INSERT INTO PC Values(7, 3.0, 8000, 500, 2899);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Toshiba', 8, 'PC');
  INSERT INTO PC Values(8, .3, 1000, 20, 299, 10);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Dell', 1, 'Laptop');
  INSERT INTO Laptop Values(1, 3.4, 4000, 125, 999, 13);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Sony', 4, 'Laptop');
  INSERT INTO Laptop Values(4, 1.2, 2000, 20, 299, 10);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('HP', 2, 'Laptop');
  INSERT INTO PC Values(2, 1.0, 8000, 500, 899, 19);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Toshiba', 9, 'Laptop');
  INSERT INTO Laptop Values(9, .4, 900, 20, 299, 10);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Toshiba', 10, 'Laptop');
  INSERT INTO Laptop Values(10, .4, 900, 20, 299, 13);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Toshiba', 11, 'Laptop');
  INSERT INTO Laptop Values(11, .4, 900, 20, 299, 10);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Toshiba', 12, 'Laptop');
  INSERT INTO Laptop Values(12, .4, 900, 20, 299, 19);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Dell', 3, 'Printer');
  INSERT INTO Printer Values(3, 199);

  INSERT INTO Product Values('Kodak', 6, 'Printer');
  INSERT INTO Printer Values(6, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL error *codes* would be in SQLCODE rather than SQLSTATE. SQLSTATE of 2000 simply means that there are no more rows. 24000 means that the cursor is in an invalid state, which is what I'd expect if you continued to use it. You should probably check the statements from outside your code to ensure you *do* get more than one row.

---

Having said that, you also have a few suspect things in your code. The first is that you allocate 128 byte for a password then immediately leak it by setting the pointer to the return value of `getpass()`. The second is your exit condition for the outer loop, when `maker == -1` causes a break. Since `maker` is a character array, it will never *be* -1.

You should also examine (and tell us) the actual output of your program - that will give vital clues as to where the problem is occurring.

---

And, based on your insert statements, one row is all you'll get. You insert a Dell laptop and a Dell printer but your first cursor query only looks for laptops and PCs (of which there are 1 and 0 respectively).

Hence 2000 (no more data) is the correct response from the database.

Now you may think that your second query should pick up the printer, and it would have if it had run. Unfortunately, because of the 'no data' from the first query, the second query is skipped altogether and it returns to the outer loop.

You can probably do this as a single query if you add the printer bit as another union and just select constants for the speed, RAM and HD size. Of course, you'll need an extra column to differentiate between the two types (with and without those fields).

Alternatively, you could give each query its own error handling code so that the second isn't skipped when the first stops.

Comment: Thank you paxdiablo.  I am using the book "Database Management Systems" ed 3, which states the following about error codes:  "SQLCODE is the older of the two and is defined to return some negative value when an error condition arises, without specifying further just what error a particular negative integer denotes.  SQLSTATE, introduced in the SQL-92 standard for the first time, associates predefined values with several common error conditions, thereby introducing some uniformity to how errors are reported.

Comment: I've added the output to the program.  I will also add the inserts, since it's not reporting all the output it should :-\

Comment: @Matt8541, based on your additions, DB2 is doing the right thing. See my update for details.